# Javascript add string variable to response

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, text, response

So I have this response for a node.js program I'm using

```
'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="tts.mp3"'
```

Instead of tts.mp3 I have a variable called textToConvert.
How can I add `textToConvert.slice(0,10)`, and add .mp3 to the end of it to have that as the name of the mp3 file instead of tts.mp3?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As in... concatenate the strings with `+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="' + textToConvert.slice(0, 10) + '.mp3"'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newResponse = response.replace(
    /(filename=")(\w+\.mp3)(")/, '$1' + textToConvert.slice(0, 10) + '.mp3$3');
```